# Adding dependencies in Modules - Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have a Module and Component for a class when satisfy the dependency for instance of Class A.

```
            @Module
            public class ModuleA {

                private ClassA classA;

                public ModuleA(ClassA classA) {
                    this.classA = classA;
                }

                @Provides
                ClassA providesClassA(){
                   return this.classA;
                }
            }


            @Component(modules = {ModuleA})
            public interface ComponentA {

                void inject(ClassNeedingA classNeedingA);

            }

            @Module
            public class ModuleB {

                private ClassB classB;

                public ModuleB(ClassB classB) {
                    this.classB = classB;
                }

                @Provides
                ClassB providesClassB(){
                   return this.classB;
                }

            @Provides
                ClassA providesClassA(ClassA classA){
                   return classA;
                }

            }

        @Component(modules = {ModuleB})
            public interface ComponentB {

                void inject(ClassNeedingB classNeedingB);

            }

    public class classNeedingB{

    @Inject
    ClassB classB

    @Inject
    ClassA classA
    public classNeedingB{
DaggerComponentB.builder().moduleB(new ModuleB(new ClassB()).componentA(DaggerComponentA.builder().moduleA(new ModuleA(new ClassA())).build()).build().inject(); 
    }

    }
```

ModuleB is in a completely different package and I would like to satisfy the dependency of the instance of classA in ModuleB. 
How would I get dagger to inject instance of ClassA in ClassNeedingB.
So how  do i make sure that ModuleB is dependant on ModuleA.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dependencies between components to achieve what you want:

```
@Component(modules = {ModuleB}, dependencies = ComponentA.class)
    public interface ComponentB {

        void inject(ClassNeedingB classNeedingB);
    }
```

To create the link all you need is to supply your ComponentA instance to ComponentB builder:

```
ComponentB componentB = DaggerComponentDependency_ComponentB.builder()
                .moduleB(moduleB)
                .componentA(componentA)
                .build();
```

Comment: Thats what i did but it doesn't seem to work. @Inject is not able to inject object of classA

Comment: Can you please add the code for the class you're injecting to?

Comment: I have added code for classNeedingB. could u please have a look. thanks

Comment: Something's wrong with the code you added, you're using an empty constructor for ModuleA, which doesn't exist.

Comment: sorry my bad. that was a typo. i was corrected that. but issue is still there.

Comment: Try removing:
    `@Provides
                ClassA providesClassA(ClassA classA){
                   return classA;
                }`

It shouldn't be declared.

Comment: really thats not required?. You mean that dependency would be provided without it ? OK let me remove that.

Comment: It'll be provided using the provider from ModuleA

Comment: By the way, you should annotate both all of your components and all of your provider methods with @Singleton

Comment: y is that required here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135864/discussion-between-sunny-and-hanan-rofe-haim).

Comment: Cause you're providing the same ClassA/ClassB object everytime and the provider should reflect that.

Comment: ok i did the previous step  to remove @Provides ClassA providesClassA(ClassA classA){ return classA; }  but it still doesnt provide classA

Comment: Answer in chat.